# document not filtered by property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My document item looks like that: [image]

I'm trying to filter the document by `year` like that:

```
async function getBooksByYear(year: number): Promise<Book[]> {

     return BookModel.find({'year': year})
}
```

I send the request from postman: http://localhost:4000/api/books?year=1990
[image]

but it's not working - it's returning the entire document items

appreciate any help

Comment: `find` will return the entire documents for all documents that match the condition, you can add projection to the query if you want to return only specific fields of the documents

Comment: I'm not trying to `project`, I'm trying to filter by specific year and return full items that match this year

Comment: It works [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CYmhJIyS7z5), can you provide an example which does not work?

Comment: @nimrodserok I adit my question

Comment: What happen when you query the db directly? If you get the right answer this is not a mongodb question...

Comment: I agree with @nimrodserok - the problem here is most likely somewhere in how your code is building and sending the query to the database, not in how the database is responding to it. You'll need to share more code related to that, e.g. how does the routing of `/api/books` get to and from the `getBooksByYear()` function? Feels like there should be an `await` somewhere as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer is**: this property wasn't declared in the `schema`.

when I add the year to the `schema`:

```
 export const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema<Book>({
author: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "missing author name"]
},
country: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "missing country"]
},

// I add this part now
year: {
    type: Number
  }
})
```

it works :)